# Design Pattern to use existing classes

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I am at the moment struggling with which design pattern should I use. My situation is as follows:

1. I have a few existing classes e.g. Address, Client and Invoices.
2. I need to create a class let's say a javabean that comprises possibly all fields from above mentioned classes as its getters and
   setters.
3. Later on, I can create a object of the javabean and assign it to a Jasperreport as its datasource.

Can anyone suggest me which design pattern would ease my job as I don't want to reinvent the wheel?
Thank you.

Comment: can you just create class e.g. JasperReportDataObject which contains Address, Client & Invoices as fields, and then implement getters/setters based on jasper needs ?

Comment: Architeturally speaking then it would be simple "Association". Thank you.

Comment: why not, main model remains the same, this is just adaptation for JasperReport

Comment: I guess you are looking for the adapter pattern.

Comment: JasperSoft provides you facility to create a javabeans data adapter...http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v611/working-collection-javabeans-data-adapter..         hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For such a case, where you want to mix multiple classes functionalities into one object, you can use **[Mixin design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)** Some languages support Multi-inheritance, but sometimes it is hard to control what gets overridden. I don't recommend to create an Inheritance Chain, because it adds overhead and makes your code harder to read and debug.